# SurefireBooterForkException- org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable

Tags: docker, java-8, itext, bouncycastle, bamboo

Local Environment:

Windows 10
JDK 1.8
Maven 3.6.3
SpringBoot 2.0.9
Surefire 2.21.0
bcprov-jdk15on v.1.58
itextpdf 5.5.13

There are no issues on my local development environment.  All test are successful and "mvn package" produces a war file.

Here are log snippets from that build:

```
[DEBUG] boot(compact) classpath:  surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar  surefire-api-2.21.0.jar  surefire-logg
er-api-2.21.0.jar  test-classes  classes  dsocore-core-sb2test-1.4-client.jar  dsocore-core-sb2test-
1.4-tests.jar  parserWrapper-1.7.jar  commons-logging-1.2.jar  log4j-1.2.17.jar  spring-boot-starter
-web-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-starter-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.9.RELEA
SE.jar  spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  logback-classic-1.2.3.jar  logback-core-1.2.3
.jar  log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar  log4j-api-2.10.0.jar  jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar  javax.annotation-api
-1.3.2.jar  snakeyaml-1.19.jar  spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.
9.8.jar  jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar  jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar  spring-boot-st
arter-tomcat-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar  tomcat-embed-el-8.5.39.jar  tomcat-emb
ed-websocket-8.5.39.jar  hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar  validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar  jboss
-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar  spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-ao
p-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-expression-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar  spring-boot
-actuator-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEA
SE.jar  spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  aspectjweaver-1.8.14.jar  spring-boot-starter-jdb
c-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  HikariCP-2.7.9.jar  spring-jdbc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  javax.transaction-api-1.2.j
ar  hibernate-core-5.2.18.Final.jar  hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar  javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar
 antlr-2.7.7.jar  jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar  dom4j-2.1.1.jar  hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final
.jar  spring-data-jpa-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar  spring-data-commons-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar  spring-orm-5.0.13.
RELEASE.jar  spring-aspects-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-starter-mail-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-c
ontext-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-context-support-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  javax.mail-1.6.2.jar  activati
on-1.1.jar  commons-lang3-3.7.jar  jose4j-0.5.6.jar  slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar  spring-boot-configuration
-processor-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  json-path-2.4.0.jar  json-smart-2.3.jar  accessors-smart-1.2.jar  asm-
5.0.4.jar  spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar  spring-beans-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-core-5.0.13.R
ELEASE.jar  spring-jcl-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-tx-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  simpleapi-4.3.0.jar  bts-en
cryption-api-1.2.1-Final-only-library.jar  db2jcc4-4.14.113.jar  itextpdf-5.5.13.jar  springfox-swag
ger2-2.9.2.jar  swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar  swagger-models-1.5.20.jar  jackson-annotations-2.9.0
.jar  springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar  springfox-core-2.9.2.jar  springfox-schema-2.9.2.jar  springfox-swagg
er-common-2.9.2.jar  guava-20.0.jar  classmate-1.3.4.jar  spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar  spri
ng-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar  mapstruct-1.2.0.Final.jar  springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar  spr
ingfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar  jjwt-0.7.0.jar  jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar  jackson-core-2.9.8.jar  nim
bus-jose-jwt-5.1.jar  jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar  spring-boot-starter-test-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring
-boot-test-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  junit-4.12.jar  mock
ito-core-2.15.0.jar  byte-buddy-1.7.11.jar  byte-buddy-agent-1.7.11.jar  objenesis-2.6.jar  hamcrest
-core-1.3.jar  hamcrest-library-1.3.jar  jsonassert-1.5.0.jar  xmlunit-core-2.5.1.jar  spring-test-5
.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-test-dbunit-1.3.0.jar  dbunit-2.5.3.jar  commons-collections-3.2.2.jar  po
i-ooxml-3.14.jar  poi-3.14.jar  commons-codec-1.11.jar  poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar  xmlbeans-2.6.0.j
ar  stax-api-1.0.1.jar  curvesapi-1.03.jar  assertj-core-3.9.1.jar  h2-1.4.199.jar  javax.el-api-3.0
.0.jar  bcprov-jdk15on-1.58.jar  system-rules-1.18.0.jar  json-20200518.jar  javax.interceptor-api-1
.2.2.jar  surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar
[DEBUG] Forking command line: cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Java\amzn-jdk1.8.0_322\jre\bin\java -Xmx1024m -jar C
:\Users\jjones\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire5326744249637996756\surefirebooter7532406846290304926.jar C
:\Users\jjones\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire5326744249637996756 2023-07-28T11-46-28_026-jvmRun1 surefir
e183475088157606778tmp surefire_03570139683691485110tmp"
[INFO] Running com.bts.dso.controllers.AutoCompleteControllerTest
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUn
it4ClassRunner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.9.RELEASE)

Hibernate: drop table DSO_REQUEST if exists
Hibernate: drop table DSO_RESPONSE if exists
Hibernate: drop table DSO_SERVICE if exists
```

**<...snip....>**

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 103, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:37 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-28T11:47:36-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The issue arises when the code is pushed to our Stash repository and a Bamboo build starts.  Bamboo runs build tasks on Docker.  Our Docker image is the same is the same as my local, with the exception of it runs on Alpine Linux as opposed to Window 10.

Docker Environment:
Alpine Linux
JDK 1.8
Maven 3.6.3
SpringBoot 2.0.9
Surefire 2.21.0
bcprov-jdk15on v.1.58
itextpdf 5.5.13

This is a snippet from the error:

```
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:15    [DEBUG] boot(compact) classpath:  surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar  surefire-api-2.21.0.jar  surefire-logger-api-2.21.0.jar  test-classes  classes  dsocore-core-sb2test-1.4-client.jar  dsocore-core-sb2test-1.4-tests.jar  parserWrapper-1.7.jar  commons-logging-1.2.jar  log4j-1.2.17.jar  spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-starter-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  logback-classic-1.2.3.jar  logback-core-1.2.3.jar  log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar  log4j-api-2.10.0.jar  jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar  javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar  snakeyaml-1.19.jar  spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar  jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar  jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar  spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar  tomcat-embed-el-8.5.39.jar  tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.39.jar  hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar  validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar  jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar  spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-aop-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-expression-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar  spring-boot-actuator-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  aspectjweaver-1.8.14.jar  spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  HikariCP-2.7.9.jar  spring-jdbc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar  hibernate-core-5.2.18.Final.jar  hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar  javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar  antlr-2.7.7.jar  jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar  dom4j-2.1.1.jar  hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar  spring-data-jpa-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar  spring-data-commons-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar  spring-orm-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-aspects-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-starter-mail-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-context-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-context-support-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  javax.mail-1.6.2.jar  activation-1.1.jar  commons-lang3-3.7.jar  jose4j-0.5.6.jar  slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar  spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  json-path-2.4.0.jar  json-smart-2.3.jar  accessors-smart-1.2.jar  asm-5.0.4.jar  spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar  spring-beans-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-core-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-jcl-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-tx-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  simpleapi-4.3.0.jar  bts-encryption-api-1.2.1-Final-only-library.jar  db2jcc4-4.14.113.jar  itextpdf-5.5.13.jar  springfox-swagger2-2.9.2.jar  swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar  swagger-models-1.5.20.jar  jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar  springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar  springfox-core-2.9.2.jar  springfox-schema-2.9.2.jar  springfox-swagger-common-2.9.2.jar  guava-20.0.jar  classmate-1.3.4.jar  spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar  spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar  mapstruct-1.2.0.Final.jar  springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar  springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar  jjwt-0.7.0.jar  jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar  jackson-core-2.9.8.jar  nimbus-jose-jwt-5.1.jar  jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar  spring-boot-starter-test-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-test-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar  junit-4.12.jar  mockito-core-2.15.0.jar  byte-buddy-1.7.11.jar  byte-buddy-agent-1.7.11.jar  objenesis-2.6.jar  hamcrest-core-1.3.jar  hamcrest-library-1.3.jar  jsonassert-1.5.0.jar  xmlunit-core-2.5.1.jar  spring-test-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar  spring-test-dbunit-1.3.0.jar  dbunit-2.5.3.jar  commons-collections-3.2.2.jar  poi-ooxml-3.14.jar  poi-3.14.jar  commons-codec-1.11.jar  poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar  xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar  stax-api-1.0.1.jar  curvesapi-1.03.jar  assertj-core-3.9.1.jar  h2-1.4.199.jar  javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar  bcprov-jdk15on-1.58.jar  system-rules-1.18.0.jar  json-20200518.jar  javax.interceptor-api-1.2.2.jar  surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:15    [DEBUG] Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd /data && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024m -jar /data/target/surefire/surefirebooter1931704697229608392.jar /data/target/surefire 2023-07-28T16-26-15_347-jvmRun1 surefire4038452741768507455tmp surefire_07623327457248742248tmp
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] 
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] Results:
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] 
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] 
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] Total time:  53.268 s
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-28T16:26:16Z
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project googleservice: There are test failures.
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] 
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] Please refer to /data/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] 
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project googleservice: There are test failures.
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    Please refer to /data/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    There was an error in the forked process
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
build   28-Jul-2023 12:26:16    org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
```

I have read about itext issues with BouncyCastle.  We need BouncyCastle for encryption as well as for use with itextpdf.  I see that itextpdf uses BouncyCastle 1.49, where we are using 1.58.  However, I have no issues building locally.  The errors only occur building with Bamboo via Docker .  Any ideas of the cause, or ways to find the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this issue and it had nothing to do with bouncycastle.  Increasing memory for the maven-surefir-plugin to 2048 fixed the issue.  The bouncycastle errors were the syptom, not the problem.

```
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          **<argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>**
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Guessing that there was not enough memory for surefire/JUnit testing.